# horizontal form with too many space left

Tags: bulma

I have a form like this (it is a Rails app, this is an ERB file)

```html
<fieldset class="mb-3">
  <legend>Dados de acesso</legend>
  <div class="field is-horizontal">
    <div class="field-label is-normal">
      <label class="label">E-mail e senha</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field-body">
      <div class="field">
        <p class="control is-expanded">
          <%= text_field_tag(:email, @user.email, class: 'input')%>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <p class="control is-expanded">
          <%= text_field_tag(:password, @user.password, type: 'password', class: 'input')%>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

it does make the form horizontal but it also kinda pushes the form to the right:

[image]

see the space between the fieldset and the `E-mail` label

[image]

I tried deleting the `fieldset` tag but it makes no difference.

Is there a way to kinda push the form to the left?

Comment: This is probably by design to vertically align the labels, when there are more than one. However, you should be able to manipulate the field-label as usual, maybe with something like min-widht:0 or the like. What have you tried?

Comment: no, this project was abandoned unfortunately and now I'm using Tailwind on a different project